# How to watch http requests which are send by my nodejs app?

Tags: node.js

I have nodejs application. It makes some https requests to some api.

I have some floating problem. Sometimes I got ECONNRESET error. I don't know why. I try to do same in browser - its ok. I try it with postman - its ok. I try it with Fiddler composer - its is ok. But it is not ok in my node app.

How I can debug https request wich my nodejs app sends?

I know tools like fiddler to watch http requests wich are sends from browser, but fiddler doesn't track cmd and node.

Also I tried Wireshark but it shows packets, not http request.

I tried http_debug (npm module) and got that I get 200 each time, but after that I get ECONNRESET each time.

I can not access server logs like access_log/error_log.

I have only client side part of my application. I don't have backend so I can use relic or any other server tools to track logs etc.

Here is code how I make request and handle exception:

```
var defaultOptions = {
  hostname: 'host',
  path: '/',
  method: 'GET',
  agent: false,
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Basic token'
  }
};
  var requestOptions = extend(defaultOptions, {
    path: 'url'
  });
  https.get(requestOptions, function (response) {
    response.on('error', function () {
      logger.debug('response error: ', arguments)
    });
    response.pipe(tmpZipStream);
  }).on('error', function (error) {
    logger.error('ERROR!!!111');
    throw new Error(error); // FIXME here is exception, must have fix
  });
```

Comment: add Your server and app to newrelic it will log exceptions in readable way and You can catch the point of failure

Comment: @num8er: That won't help figure out why a connection is being reset.

Comment: if You use nodejs behind nginx so enable access_log, error_log

Comment: Thank you for you responses. I added two more lines to answer your questions and messages.

Comment: why not to use request module and catch exception inside callback function? or how about: https.get('some url', (res) => {}).on('error', console.error);

Comment: @SharikovVladislav can You paste Your code part that has request to some api?

Comment: @num8er I copy pasted my code. I don't have problems witch catching exception. It is catched. I have problem 'why this exception happens?'